# How to interpret and modify a dBase (.dbf) file?

Tags: datafile, format

I'm working with dBASE (`.dbf`) files for a project using a GIS software because it seems that they are more efficient. I've converted several `.xml` files to `.dbf` with OpenOffice 3.4 and loaded into the GIS however in some columns, the fields that appeared with different numbers in Open Office, turn to a series of one (1) in the GIS attribute table.

This is an example of my first row of one element:

```
Na,N,6,2
```

I think that changing the first row of every columns of my `.dbf` file I can set up the properties.

**First question**:

I would like to know what does it means every character. I know that the first (e.g. Na) is the name of the field, N is probably the type? Number? I've no idea about the third and the forth (red and blue arrows).

**Second question**:

Why if I write `Na` when I load the file it become `NA`, with capitalized letters?

[image: .dbf open with OpenOffice]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** directly manipulate the .dbf-files. There is an ODBC driver that does all the low-level work for you. Save yourself the headaches.

Comment: How can I adjust it whit this ODBC driver? Note that my file was originally an `.xlm`

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm not really sure about the interpretation but from that it seems that `N` is the type `6` _Field length in binary_ (a number with 6 digits?) and `2` _Field decimal count in binary_ so my example seems formatted for a number like this 100000.00 ; I'm right?